# PostgresSQL Join Into existing table

Tags: postgresql

before I ask this question I want to lead with full disclosure that this is for a class project so I am not looking for an answer just some guidance on what could be wrong and where to look. I need to create a table and then add data from two other tables. I can create the table, add the initial data but when attempting to add data from another table based on a primary key I get a successful execution message but either nothing happens or all fields are NULL. I am trying to pull data from 2 specific columns we can call t2.c1 and t2.c2 into table 1, Any guidance would be appreciated.

Here is an example of the code I am executing

```sql
INSERT INTO t1
SELECT (I have tried * and specific column names)
FROM table 1 t1
INNER JOIN table 2 t2 ON t1.primary_key=t2.primary_key
ORDER BY t1.primary_key;
```

If I remove the INSERT INTO command I receive the correct information but it is not added to the table, which I need to do for this task.

Comment: Hi Meenan, how are you? Could you provide the ddl of the tables and the result of the select? Also, is there any error after running the sql file with the insert command? The result of the sql should have the format of your t1 table.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am using Postgresql. When using SELECT * I receive INSERT has more expression than target columns. When I use SELECT t1.column,t1.column2 I receive a successfully query insert 0 1649 but it only adds 900 rows and columns of NULL vs the data I am looking for.